# Cannot delete my database records

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, referential-integrity

I have these two tables:

```
class Performance(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'performances'
    id_ = Column(Integer, Sequence('performance_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    competitor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('competitors.id_'), index=True)
    start_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, index=True)
    end_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, index=True)
    target = Column(Float, nullable=True)
    actual = Column(Float, nullable=True)

    competitor = relationship("Competitor", backref="performances")


class TargetAdjustment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'target_adjustments'
    id_ = Column(Integer, Sequence('target_adjustments_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    competitor_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    start_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Float, nullable=True)

    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([competitor_id, start_date], [Performance.competitor_id, Performance.start_date]), {})

    performance = relationship('Performance', backref=backref("adjustment", uselist=False))


Index('target_adjustment_index', TargetAdjustment.competitor_id, TargetAdjustment.start_date, unique=True)
```

(amongst others but these are the key ones for my question)

Now I need to delete records from these tables but when they both contain records I cannot delete them!

I am doing this:

```
competition = competitor.competition

adjustment_query = DBSession.query(TargetAdjustment).filter(
    TargetAdjustment.competitor_id == competitor.id_
).filter(
    or_(
        TargetAdjustment.start_date <= competition.start_date,
        TargetAdjustment.start_date >= competition.end_date
    )
)
# delete any extraneous adjustment data for this competitor
log.warning("before: {}".format(adjustment_query.count()))

adjustment_query.delete()

DBSession.flush()

log.warning("after: {}".format(adjustment_query.count()))

# delete any extraneous performance data for this competitor
DBSession.query(Performance).filter(
    Performance.competitor_id == competitor.id_
).filter(
    or_(
        Performance.start_date <= competition.start_date,
        Performance.end_date >= competition.end_date
    )
).delete()
DBSession.flush()
```

When I try to delete 'performances' records, the log statements demonstrate that I have deleted the equivalent 'target_adjustments' record,

> WARNI: before: 0
>
> WARNI: after: 0

But I still get this error.

> "IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`target_adjustments`, CONSTRAINT `target_adjustments_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`competitor_id`, `start_date`) REFERENCES `performances`
>   (`competitor_id`, `start_date`))') 'DELETE FROM performances WHERE
>   performances.competitor_id = %s AND (performances.start_date <= %s OR
>   performances.end_date >= %s)' (1128L, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31,
>   23, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 23, 0))"

Why can I not delete the performances records?

Comment: Apparently MySQL thinks otherwise. Instead of guessing, you could actually check if you had any referencing data left in target_adjustments table

Comment: I have addressed this, the log messages show that there are no matching records.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

My delete query was not actually matching all records so there was still an adjustment record in the table when I was trying to delete performances.

The updated code is as follows:

```
adjustment_query = DBSession.query(TargetAdjustment).filter(
    TargetAdjustment.competitor_id == competitor.id_
).filter(
    or_(
        TargetAdjustment.start_date <= competition.start_date,
        TargetAdjustment.start_date >= (competition.end_date - timedelta(days=1)) # adjust to match performance end date query
    )
)
```

luckily, I know that performances always cover exactly one day - for now.